# Why must accessor functions be const? Where is the vulnerability?

Tags: c++, oop, constants, encapsulation, getter

Professors hammered it into my head when I was in school, associates have jumped down my throat for it on code reviews, and it's in pretty much every C++ textbook out there: "accessor" (aka "selector" or ["getter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getter)) methods must be marked `const`. If it doesn't change or mutate the data, then mark it `const`.

Why? How could the invocation of an accessor modify the private data?

In the following example, I have set up a simple class and one accessor. How can `getBrand()` be used to modify the private data? In my eyes, it can't; so why do we need to mark it `const`?

In other words, am I correct in saying that it is impossible for `getBrand()` to be used, in practice, to mutate a private property?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Cheese {
public:
    Cheese(std::string brand):brand_(brand) {}
    std::string getBrand() { return brand_; } // Intentionally not marked const
private:
    std::string brand_;
};

int main() {
    Cheese cheddar("Cabot clothbound");
    std::cout << "Brand: " << cheddar.getBrand() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Generally compilers can optimize better if they can assume data won't change (`mutable` notwithstanding)

Comment: Well for one if you have a `const` reference or an instance of the type you won't be able to invoke the non-const members.

Comment: @AndyG, true, but beside the point; I'm asking from an OOP best practice perspective. @Captain Oblivious, doesn't speak to the question; why then not remove the ``const`` references from the other objects?

Comment: Think about the violations of assumptions and how impactful they could be if down the road you suddenly stopped promising that `getBrand` wouldn't change any data, but had no way of indicating as much

Comment: @kmiklas If you had `const Cheese cheddar("Cabot clothbound");` How would you get information if the getters are not `const`?

Comment: Also, if you mark a member as `mutable` it can be changed inside a `const` function.  This is required for things like mutexs where you might need to lock it in the function for thread safety.

Comment: @AndyG, compilers cannot optimize better based only on `const` annotations because `const_cast` is not UB. Compilers that figure out that a value is never mutated would be able to figure it out regardless of whether `const` was used.

Comment: `Const` is a tool for developers, not compilers. If you hate const correctness, you don't have to use it, but there is a wide consensus that it's one very fine feature of C++. Without `const` at the end of your `getBrand` method, you wouldn't be able to get the brand off of a `const Cheese`.

Comment: It is not about an evil user that will steal your data.

Comment: @zneak `const_cast` is not UB, but writing to a variable you've `const_cast`ed generally is. Also, I think [this video from Jason Turner](https://youtu.be/zBkNBP00wJE?t=1665) was pretty enlightening about the performance benefits of marking `const` (I've marked it at the appropriate time. Turns out it *did* need the `const` keyword)

Comment: @AndyG, it's only UB if the object was originally declared `const`, which cover a vanishingly small portion of all the objects used in any non-trivial program. In practice, that's almost only ever the case for global variables. Notice that you benefit from marking global variables `const`, and not from telling the compiler that you're using `const` methods to manipulate them (although that's kind of an unavoidable side effect).

Comment: @AndyG, to illustrate the point, see [this example](https://godbolt.org/g/nvQjgV). The compiler is able to determine that the argument to `square` is constant and it passes 16 directly to `printf` (`mov esi, 16`). When the compiler can't tell that the object was declared `const` in the first place, like [in this example](https://godbolt.org/g/TtjCPd), the optimization can't happen and you get the runtime multiplication with two loads from the same reference. It has to do so because it can't be sure that `kill_aa` doesn't modify the reference, despite it being `const`.

Answer (score 11):

It's actually very simple: If the method is not const, you would not be able to use it on `const` objects - but you do want to be able to use it. With your class, you can't implement

```
void print_brand(const Cheese& cheese);
```

(unless you const-cast, which you shouldn't do).

Also, if you do make it const, instead of returning a copy of your string - which may or may not get optimized away, you could implement:

```
const std::string& getBrand() const { return brand_; }
```

which returns a reference, or perhaps

```
std::string_view getBrand() const { return brand_; }
```

that does not "commit" your API to the string class (read about `string_view` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view); it was only officially added to the language in C++17, but is available as `std::experimental::string_view` with recent compilers).

Answer (score 3):

> where is the vulnerability?

The answer is that function names can lie, but interfaces containing references to const cannot.

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// this function name lies
void i_wont_touch_your_cheese(std::string& s)
{
    // uh-oh - I lied!
    s = "lol, I touched your cheese!";    
}

// this one cannot. The compiler won't allow it
void i_really_wont_touch_your_cheese(const std::string& s)
{
    // compiler error here!
    // cheese is safe
    s = "lol, I touched your cheese!";    
}

int main() {
    auto cheese = std::string("untouched cheese");
    i_wont_touch_your_cheese(cheese);
    std::cout << cheese << std::endl;

    cheese = "more untouched cheese";
    i_really_wont_touch_your_cheese(cheese);
    std::cout << cheese << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that's the main reason, but definitely worth a +1. I remember the pain of realizing methods don't do what they claim to do...

Answer (score 2):

*Strictly speaking* the method you've written doesn't mutate class members. If you marked it `const` the compiler completely prevents it from mutating members. But let's dig a little deeper here.

Typically you write code once but read/review it many times. Marking a method `const` allows future readers to look at it and *instantly know* that the method can't change the class state because the compiler would catch it. For example if you accidentally write `size_t empty() const { return size_ = 0; }` (where `size_` is a member variable) the compiler will catch your typo. If you hadn't marked the method const you would have a subtle bug.

But more importantly, `const` methods can only call other `const` methods. Consider if you have a method that takes the class state as input, does a bunch of work and returns a result. If the `getter` methods it uses to do its work are non-const then the long, complicated method *also* has to be non-const which then makes code comprehension *much* harder.

Answer (score 1):

Function with keyword `const` guarantee that use her, don't change object which was given. So if you want give to print object to some function or especially to `operator<<` outside class you should use only method with keyword `const`.

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream& str, const Object& obj)
{
    return str << obj.someFunctionConst() << std::endl;
}
```

function with error (compile error)

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream& str, const Object& obj)
{
     return str << obj.someFunctionWithoutConst() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Here you reiterate exactly what all my professors, associates, and textbooks have said: "you should use only method with keyword const." The question is not **when** ``const`` should be used, but **why**?

Answer (score 0):

`const` is not about vulneratilities! Thecnically it doesn't enforce security, safety or anything. Nothing stops you from applying const-cast to remove it or using keyword `mutable` to change something.

`const` helps to make your code cleaner. See [Const-Correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) article with good explanation of the concept.

1. When you look at something with `const` you would reasonably expect it not change the state. The declaration `int Class:foo() const;` tells me `foo()` won't change the object's state and it is ok to call it from anywhere.
2. `const` is infectious. The more you use it the more you have to use it. `bool Class::bar();` would have to be `const` if it needs to call `foo()`.
3. Same applies in reverse direction. If you are passing `const &` to a function: `void zoo(const Class &cls);` then you know `zoo()` won't be able to modify `cls`'s state.

Comment: I see too, that it's not good idea give some parameters by `const &` because you can miss `const` ~architect software ( it's slopped allusion to `mutable`)